# import mysql data to a table, edit/clone rows, and insert new rows

Tags: php, mysql

Is there already any software that will allow me to select a table or row from existing DB, edit that table, add new rows, or clone existing ones, then insert the new rows back into the DB?

Read: i want to ADD this data, do not want to update/replace existing data.

PHP5, and MySQL 5

Answer (score 1):

There's [`PHPMyAdmin`](http://www.phpmyadmin.net), which will let you to pretty much anything to a database.

You can clone rows by editing and selecting "insert as new row" (may have to blank out the primary key if you have one).

Comment: phpmyadmin is a little too technical for my user's purposes. Since i only want to allow them to ADD

Comment: @Patrick - if you have user-based permissions on the database, when they login to PHPMyAdmin, they'll only be able to do what their user's allowed to do :) ..though I do agree that it's probably overkill for what you're looking at, it can be setup to handle it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) is a decent GUI put out by MySQL that should handle all of that.  I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: You should edit your question to mention that.  I'll leave this answer here just for the sake of people who find this thread later.

Answer (score 0):

There's also HeidiSQL which is a windows client for managing MySQL databases: 
http://www.heidisql.com/

And there's jHeidi from the same site that's java based and so should run on other operating systems.